# Recompose when back to activity

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have an activity with a list of items (LazyColumn). When I click on an item, it launches a new activity to edit the item. If I change the item and save it, go back to the main activity and I want to recompose the list.
I am initiating Jetpack compose and I need help to recompose the layout.
I have this code but this does not work.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun content(
    viewModel: MealsViewModel,
    selected: (Meal) -> Unit,
    longClicked: (Meal) -> Unit
) {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    LazyColumn(
        state = listState,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp),
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(items = viewModel.meals.value) { i, meal ->
                MealListItem(viewModel.meals.value[i], selected, longClicked)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Compose implies a single Activity approach. Use Compose Navigation to switcn between composables. Recomposition occurs automatically when State changes, see sampsel here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state

Comment: just do not use two activities